# Function Pointer Arduino as Callback Bluefruit Library

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have been trying to pass a callback to the `setConnectCallback()` function in the Bluefruit Library. When I pass the function names `connect_callback` into `setConnectCallback()` 
I am getting the error `invalid use of non-static member function of type 'void (AumeBluetooth::)()'`

The function `setConnectCallback()` looks like it is asking for a function pointer:

exerpt from Adafruit_BLE Arduino Library:

```
/******************************************************************************/
/*!
    @brief  Set handle for connect callback
    @param[in] fp function pointer, NULL will discard callback
*/
/******************************************************************************/
void Adafruit_BLE::setConnectCallback( void (*fp) (void) )
{
  this->_connect_callback = fp;
  install_callback(fp != NULL, EVENT_SYSTEM_CONNECT, -1);
}
```

I have a class "AumeBluetooth" defined as such, which I attempted to implement a function pointer to call `connect_callback`:

.h

```
class AumeBluetooth {


  public:

    bool isConnected = false;
    Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI *_ble;
    void error(const __FlashStringHelper*err);
    void begin();
    AumeBluetooth();
    void loop();
    void connect_callback(void);

};
```

.cpp

```
#include "AumeBluetooth.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include "Adafruit_BLE.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_BluefruitLE_UART.h"
#include "BluefruitConfig.h"


AumeBluetooth::AumeBluetooth() {

}


void AumeBluetooth::begin() {

  isConnected = false;

  Adafruit_BluefruitLE_SPI ble(BLUEFRUIT_SPI_CS, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_IRQ, BLUEFRUIT_SPI_RST);
  _ble = &ble;

   if ( !_ble->begin() )
  {
    error(F("Couldn't find Bluefruit, make sure it's in CoMmanD mode & check wiring?"));
  }

  _ble->echo(false);

  _ble->info();
  _ble->setMode(BLUEFRUIT_MODE_DATA);

  void (AumeBluetooth::*cc)(void) = &AumeBluetooth::connect_callback;
  ble.setConnectCallback(this->*cc);


}

void AumeBluetooth::connect_callback(void) {

       Serial.print("BLUETOOTH IS CONNECTED"); 
       isConnected = true;
}

}

Not sure what to do try next. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

setConnectCallback is looking for a static function pointer.  As the error message says, you are passing it a non-static function pointer.

Your callback function must be a static function - either a free function, or a class function that is specifically designated 'static' and therefore has no access to class variables.

This is a tricky API, because it also looks like the function parameter list is (void), which means you don't have a way to pass in an index or a pointer to tie it to a class instance.  You only get one callback to a static function, and it is up to your code to know which class instance the callback might be for.

So, your connect_callback function won't be able to set a class variable isConnected inside the callback.  You will only be able to access global/static variables.

I would expect the begin() and loop() function calls also to be static, non-class functions.  It looks like maybe you are trying to put a class wrapper around code that doesn't have to be a class.

Comment: Thank you for quick and informative response. Thanks again!

Comment: stackoverflow customs: Thank you comments aren't necessary, but if your question is answered you can express thanks by marking the answer as "Accepted"